# Stuck on fastboot mode, usb debugging turned off

Tags: adb, factory-reset, fastboot, usb-debugging

I rooted my Alldocube iplay 30 pro and uninstalled a few system apps before rebooting. Right after, it got stuck in fastboot mode and i cant do anything about it. USB debugging is turned off and I tried wiping cache/data but it's still the same.

What can i do?

Comment: Reflash system partition.

Comment: But doesn't it require USB debugging turned on?

Comment: No. It doesn't.

Comment: How can I do this? Which software do I need to install on my PC? I tried searching but they say they require USB debugging turned on. Can you maybe link me a guide if there is any? Sorry, I'm a noob at this

Comment: Thank! I flashed the stock rom through SP Flash tool and it worked